# Let $X$ be a countable set. Then which of the following are true?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a countable set. Then which of the following are true?

1. There exists a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ is complete
2. There exists a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ is not complete
3. There exists a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ is compact
4. There exists a metric $d$ on $X$ such that $(X,d)$ is not compact

My attempt:-

1.$(\mathbb N,d)$, where $d$ is a discrete metric space is complete

2. $(\mathbb N,d)$, where $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is not a complete
3. I am not able to judge
4. $(\mathbb N,d)$, where $d$ is a discrete metric space is not compact.

Comment: $|x-y|$ is a complete metric on $\mathbb{N}$. However, it's not a complete metric on $\mathbb{Q}$. In any case, the question is whether for *any* discrete space $X$ you can construct a metric $d$ with the given properties. So it's not enough to give examples, you want to either prove that you can *always* construct such a $d$, *never* construct such a $d$, or perhaps the existence of $d$ depends on the space $X$ in question.

Comment: For instance, your example 1 can be generalized to say for *any* space $X$, the discrete metric $d$ on $X$ is complete. So 1 is true. Similarly, 4 can be generalized to say for *any* space $X$, the discrete metric $d$ on $X$ makes $(X,d)$ not compact, so 4 is also true.

Comment: I will revise my earlier statement - since any countable set $X$ is in bijection with any other countable set $Y$, it is enough to give an example $(Y,d')$, and through the bijection you can obtain a metric on $(X,d)$ with the given property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Existence of compact/complete metric on countable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267085/existence-of-compact-complete-metric-on-countable-set)

Answer (score 4):

All four options are correct. Consider the spaces $X_1=\big\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb N\big\}$ and $X_2=\{0\}\cup\big\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \Bbb N\big\}$ with usual distance metric $|\cdot|$ on $\Bbb R$.

Now consider a bijection between $X$ with these spaces, say $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection, where $Y$ is either $X_1$ or $X_2$. then, $d(a,b)=|f(a)-f(b)|$ for all $a,b\in X$ is a metric on $X$.

$X_1$ gives you options 2. and 4. and $X_2$ gives you options 1. and 3.

Comment: Countable also includes finite and if a metric space is finite then it is always compact. In such case option $(4)$ is false.

Comment: @AntonioClaire Since a finite metric space is compete too, as the only Cauchy sequences are eventually constant, $(2)$ is false too.